# How do I pick a fractional sample from an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sample

I know that ruby has `myarray.sample(i)` to sample `i` elements from an array. My problem is that the number of elements are not integers.

i.e I would like a method `mysample` such that if I call `myarray.mysample(1.5)` 10 times, the number of elements I get should be close to 15.

With `sample`, I will get either 10 or 20 depending on the int conversion. Similarly, if I call `myarray.mysample(.25)` I want it to return an element with `0.25` probability (that is, it should return one element one times out of four, and three times out of four, it should return an empty array/nil).

How do I do this?

My attempt so far:

```
def mysample(array,s)
  ints = array.sample(s.floor)
  if (Random.rand > s - s.floor)
    ints << array.sample
  end
  return ints
end
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What does it mean that "the number of elements are not integers"? And if you have an array with, for example, 100 elements, could you explain further what "pick an element with 0.25 probability" means? I know what it means to say that the probability of picking a given element is 0.25, but not sure what your example means.

Comment: In my case, it should return empty for three times out of four, and it should return one random element one time out of four.

Comment: @sawa removed that statement, and reworded.

Comment: I see what you're asking. Thanks for explaining. Are there any other constraints, such as should the number of elements returned not exceed `ceil(r)` when you call `my_array.sample(r)`? Or should the number of elements returned always be between `floor(r)` and `ceil(r)`?

Comment: `do myarray.mysample(1.25) such that if I call myarray.mysample(1.5)` also does not make sense.

Comment: @sawa Updated, sorry about my messy English.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @ZachKemp  Is it needed to maintain the spirit of *SO* or what ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: yes, that (this isn't a free programming service), and I think it would help clarify the question.

Comment: How it is supposed to know that `myarray.mysample(.25)` `should return one element one times out of four, and three times out of four, it should return an empty array/nil`? Why not two elements once out of eight times? Why not four elements once out of sixteen times?

Comment: @ZachKemp I have updated as you requested.

Comment: @ZachKemp OP did... :-)

Comment: @sawa I have clarified with a code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing my answer off of this:

> if I call `myarray.mysample(1.5)` 10 times, the number of elements I get should be close to 15.

Extending `Array` yields the following:

```
class Array
    def mysample(num)
       self.sample( ( num + rand() ).floor )
    end
end

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].mysample(2.5)
=> [1, 3]

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].mysample(2.5)
=> [4, 2, 5]

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].mysample(0.5)
=> []

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].mysample(0.5)
=> [3]

etc.
```

Comment: This is one among the various possibilities.

Comment: You could use `self.sample( ( num + rand() ).floor )`, essentially the same, and no need to extract the value of `prob`.

Comment: @NeilSlater I like that idea, that was essentially what I was hoping for.

Comment: Excellent logic, @NeilSlater +1

Answer (score 1):

To optimal argument is there to decide the spread of randomness for numbers above 1.

```
class Array
  def my_sample(number, deviation=0.3)
    if number < 1
        return sample rand(100) < number * 100 ? 1 : 0
    end
    speard = (number*deviation).to_i
    randomness = rand(-speard..speard)
    sample(number+randomness)
  end
end

p [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].my_sample(0.5) #=> []
p [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].my_sample(0.5) #=> [3]

p [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].my_sample(5) #=> [9, 2, 1, 4, 10, 7, 3]
p [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].my_sample(5) #=> [7, 2, 3, 8]
```